# Reuse code for scripts in different folders

Tags: python, python-import

Looking for a way to import `common.py` into `read.py` and `write.py` without pasting boiler-plate code in each script, and without any clunky `sys.path` foolery at the top of each script. I have already tried littering `__init__.py` everywhere.

Dir structure:

```
parent/
    common.py
    script1/
        config.json
        read.py
        write.py
        ...
    script2/
        config.json
        read.py
        write.py
        ...
    script3/
        config.json
        read.py
        write.py
        ...
    ...
```

They should all import code like this from `common.py`:

```
import sys
import logging
from pathlib import Path

import uvloop

file_path = Path(__file__).resolve()  # remove /../ in path
project_dir = file_path.parent.parent.parent
data_dir = project_dir.parent / 'data'
# Allow imports from project dir
sys.path.insert(1, str(project_dir))


def init_stuff(_file_, logger_name=None):
    uvloop.install()
    lg = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    ...
    return stuff
```

Again, to re-iterate once more, I'm looking for a better solution than having to use `sys.path`.

Answer (score 1):

`parent` should be in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable however you are calling python. e.g. if you are calling from a bash command line `export PYTHONPATH="/path/to/parent"`

Then in both `read.py` and `write.py` you would import whatever you want from common. e.g. `from common import Foo`

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from a [great article by Geir Arne Hjelle](https://realpython.com/python-import/)

> While it’s possible to organize your imports by using the current directory as well as by manipulating PYTHONPATH and even sys.path, the process is often unruly and prone to errors

He suggests to create a virtual environment for your project and install it in editable mode. By doing so you don't have to worry about reinstalling it every time you change your scripts.

Here you have the folder and file structure of your project.

```
root/
    src/
        package/
            __init__.py
            read.py
            write.py
        __init__.py
        common.py
    pyproject.toml
    setup.cfg
```

Leave those `__init__.py` files and `pyproject.toml` blank.
The `setup.cfg` typically contains details about packaging. You don't need them this time, you simply have to specify a package name (maybe not even that) and where to look for packages (ie folders with an `__init__.py` file).

```
# setup.cfg

[metadata]
name = my-package

[options]
package_dir =
    = src
packages = find:
python_requires = >=3.6

[options.packages.find]
where = src
```

Now, create a virtual environment, activate it, and then install the project in editable mode

```
...\root> python -m venv venv
...\root> venv\Scripts\activate
(venv)...\root> pip install -e .
```

For the sake of making an example, say that this is all `common.py` does

```
# common.py

print("importing common.py")
```

`common.py` is then imported in `read.py`

```
# read.py

import common

def read():
    print("reading stuff...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    read()
```

You can now run `read.py`

```
(venv)...\root> python src\package\read.py
importing common.py
reading stuff...
```

You can also open a Python console and import your scripts from there

```
>>> import common
importing common.py
>>> from package.read import read
>>> read()
reading stuff...
```

Check out [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) as well, it's a package for dependancy management and packaging that gives you practically the same result for free.